# Strange behaviour of the Eclipse project Window

Tags: android, eclipse

Starting this morning my Eclipse indigo have projects and files with gray light color.
Why?

[image]

Comment: have you moved any files around?? Looks like it can't find the files for those projects.

Comment: so don't find the files of all the projects? impossible ! Also projects are working when debug.

Comment: It looks so strange...have you tried a "clean and build" operation?

Comment: Thank you Simone, "clean and build" solved it, please write the answer and we will close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like you've enabled the "Focus on active task" feature of Mylyn. The toolbar button for it looks like [image]